# Using Multiple Live Rates Plugins

Tags: cartthrob

What's the correct way to pull multiple rates from multiple shipping plugins? I tried using the below but it generates errors:

```
<select name="shipping_option">
{exp:cartthrob:get_shipping_options shipping_plugin="shipping_ups|shipping_usps"}
    <option value="{rate_short_name}" data-price="{price}" {selected}>{rate_title} - {price}</option>
{/exp:cartthrob:get_shipping_options}
</select>
```

Am I using the shipping_plugin parameter incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That get_shipping_options tag only accepts one argument for the shipping_plugin parameter.

You can only have one shipping plugin active at a time. If you need both UPS and USPS options available at the same time, you'll need to combine those two plugins into a single plugin.

You can allow selection between those two shipping plugins using the multi_location_manager and custom_data. https://github.com/CartThrob/addon-multi-location-settings-manager

You could trigger the plugin update using an update_cart_from.

```
{exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form}
    <select name="custom_data[set_shipping]">
        <option value="shipping_ups" {if custom_data:set_shipping == "shipping_ups"}selected{/if}>UPS</option>
        <option value="shipping_usps" {if custom_data:set_shipping == "shipping_usps"}selected{/if}>USPS</option>
    </select>
    {exp:cartthrob:get_shipping_options}
    <input type="submit" value="Update Shipping Options" />
{/exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form}
```

The settings in the multi_location_manager would look like this:

[image]